# .find() in MongoDb prints multiple occurences of same document

Tags: mongodb

The following code is copied from w3schools. It displays the same output multiple times. Why?
I have shared the output at the bottom. Same rows are retrieved twice .Please Help. I am not able to get the issue

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
mycol = mydb["customers"]

mylist = [
{ "name": "Amy", "address": "Apple st 652"},
{ "name": "Hannah", "address": "Mountain 21"},
{ "name": "Michael", "address": "Valley 345"},
{ "name": "Sandy", "address": "Ocean blvd 2"},
{ "name": "Betty", "address": "Green Grass 1"},
{ "name": "Richard", "address": "Sky st 331"},
{ "name": "Susan", "address": "One way 98"},
{ "name": "Vicky", "address": "Yellow Garden 2"},
{ "name": "Ben", "address": "Park Lane 38"},
{ "name": "William", "address": "Central st 954"},
{ "name": "Chuck", "address": "Main Road 989"},
{ "name": "Viola", "address": "Sideway 1633"}
]

x = mycol.insert_many(mylist)

for x in mycol.find():
  print(x)

The output is as follows-
{'_id': ObjectId('5da749f00a2f7a69064f65e2'), 'name': 'Amy', 'address': 'Apple st 652'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da749f00a2f7a69064f65e3'), 'name': 'Hannah', 'address': 'Mountain 21'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da749f00a2f7a69064f65e4'), 'name': 'Michael', 'address': 'Valley 345'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da749f00a2f7a69064f65e5'), 'name': 'Sandy', 'address': 'Ocean blvd 2'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da749f00a2f7a69064f65e6'), 'name': 'Betty', 'address': 'Green Grass 1'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da749f00a2f7a69064f65e7'), 'name': 'Richard', 'address': 'Sky st 331'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da749f00a2f7a69064f65e8'), 'name': 'Susan', 'address': 'One way 98'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da749f00a2f7a69064f65e9'), 'name': 'Vicky', 'address': 'Yellow Garden 2'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da749f00a2f7a69064f65ea'), 'name': 'Ben', 'address': 'Park Lane 38'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da749f00a2f7a69064f65eb'), 'name': 'William', 'address': 'Central st 954'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da749f00a2f7a69064f65ec'), 'name': 'Chuck', 'address': 'Main Road 989'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da749f00a2f7a69064f65ed'), 'name': 'Viola', 'address': 'Sideway 1633'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da74a000a2f7a69064f65ef'), 'name': 'Amy', 'address': 'Apple st 652'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da74a000a2f7a69064f65f0'), 'name': 'Hannah', 'address': 'Mountain 21'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da74a000a2f7a69064f65f1'), 'name': 'Michael', 'address': 'Valley 345'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da74a000a2f7a69064f65f2'), 'name': 'Sandy', 'address': 'Ocean blvd 2'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da74a000a2f7a69064f65f3'), 'name': 'Betty', 'address': 'Green Grass 1'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da74a000a2f7a69064f65f4'), 'name': 'Richard', 'address': 'Sky st 331'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da74a000a2f7a69064f65f5'), 'name': 'Susan', 'address': 'One way 98'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da74a000a2f7a69064f65f6'), 'name': 'Vicky', 'address': 'Yellow Garden 2'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da74a000a2f7a69064f65f7'), 'name': 'Ben', 'address': 'Park Lane 38'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da74a000a2f7a69064f65f8'), 'name': 'William', 'address': 'Central st 954'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da74a000a2f7a69064f65f9'), 'name': 'Chuck', 'address': 'Main Road 989'}
{'_id': ObjectId('5da74a000a2f7a69064f65fa'), 'name': 'Viola', 'address': 'Sideway 1633'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have run this twice.  See 'Amy', she has two different object ids.  Notice there is no delete.  Every time you run this you insert the same records.  You could augment the code to delete the documents before you run it.

By the way, the ObjectId is a timestamp.  You can see the two 'Amy' records were created about 15 seconds apart.

```
replSet:PRIMARY> ObjectId("5da749f00a2f7a69064f65e2").getTimestamp()
ISODate("2019-10-16T16:48:48Z")

replSet:PRIMARY> ObjectId("5da74a000a2f7a69064f65ef").getTimestamp()
ISODate("2019-10-16T16:49:04Z")
```

You could augment the code to delete first, ya know, to clear out the data so each run has fresh new data, and no duplicates...

```
import pymongo                                                                                                                                                                      

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
mycol = mydb["customers"]

mycol.delete_many({})

mylist = [ 
{ "name": "Amy", "address": "Apple st 652"},
{ "name": "Hannah", "address": "Mountain 21"},
{ "name": "Michael", "address": "Valley 345"},
{ "name": "Sandy", "address": "Ocean blvd 2"},
{ "name": "Betty", "address": "Green Grass 1"},
{ "name": "Richard", "address": "Sky st 331"},
{ "name": "Susan", "address": "One way 98"},
{ "name": "Vicky", "address": "Yellow Garden 2"},
{ "name": "Ben", "address": "Park Lane 38"},
{ "name": "William", "address": "Central st 954"},
{ "name": "Chuck", "address": "Main Road 989"},
{ "name": "Viola", "address": "Sideway 1633"}
]

x = mycol.insert_many(mylist)

for x in mycol.find():
  print(x)
```

Comment: How to augment it? I didn't get what you said

Comment: Notice how the code has been changed to include a line `mycol.delete_many({})`

Comment: myquery1 = { "name": { $eq:"Amy" }}

mydoc = mycol.find(myquery1) Sir can you explain why this gives a syntax error?

Comment: @HarveyAndrews - you are getting a python error, not a mongo error.  This is a syntax error but simple to fix.  Need to put `$eq` in quotes.  Example.. `myquery1 = { "name": { "$eq": "Amy" }}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir. The official MongoDb documentation does not mention anything about " ".Thank you for your help

Comment: You're welcome.  This syntax stuff is more of a python requirement, not so much a mongo requirement.  Python never attempted to call mongo.  Python performed a syntax check before running the program.  It saw this syntax problem, reported an error, then aborted the run.

Answer (score 0):

While there are repeated names and addresses, it looks like every _id is unique. This would indicate that records with duplicative information were inserted into the collection, but `mycol.find()` isn't returning duplicates.

It looks like you may be repeating the same insert each time on this statement (assuming you've run this code more than once):
`mycol.insert_many(mylist)`

Comment: myquery1 = { "name": { $eq:"Amy" }} mydoc = mycol.find(myquery1) Sir can you explain why this gives a syntax error?